# Select SQL Query on another Select SQL query giving null

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am getting my phone as null, I tried adding the orders as part of my inner select query but still getting errors

```
SELECT `oid`, 
       `shipping_name` , ( SELECT `phone` 
                           FROM `users` 
                           WHERE `orders`.`uid` = `users`.`uid` 
                           AND `users`.`login`!='ExpressCheckoutUser') AS `phone` 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE orders.smsStatus = '0' 
ORDER BY `orders`.`oid` DESC
```

Comment: Without seeing sample data and detailed description of unexpected results / errors, we can only guess as to what's wrong with your query.

Comment: prove to us you have a an order for which a user has a phone that has data.  what you have looks correct; so it must be that you lack the data to return results.  Is it possible the users.login is = ExpressCheckoutUser for what you're attempting to test and thus would always be null?

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide sample data and desired output , but why not using regular left join? :

```
SELECT
    `oid`,
    `shipping_name`,
    `phone`
FROM `orders`
left join `users` 
    on `orders`.`uid` = `users`.`uid`
    AND `users`.`login` <> 'ExpressCheckoutUser'
WHERE orders.smsStatus = '0'
ORDER BY `orders`.`oid` DESC
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with left joins, even though your query works, phone is still null.

Comment: @winfredadrah that's why you have to provide sample data and desired output